# Popup menu with icon on Android

Tags: android, android-xml

My menu xml code *menu.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Single menu item 
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->

 <item android:id="@+id/back"
      android:icon="@drawable/back1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="Back" />

<item android:id="@+id/My_Profile"
      android:icon="@drawable/myprofile"
       android:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="My Profile" />

<item android:id="@+id/Job_Alert"
      android:icon="@drawable/jobalert4"
       android:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="Job Alert !" />

<item android:id="@+id/saved_job"
      android:icon="@drawable/jobapplied"
      android:title="Saved Jobs"
       />


<item android:id="@+id/Logout"
      android:icon="@drawable/logout"
      android:title="Logout" /> 
</menu>
```

I am calling menu xml like this

```
     PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), v);
 popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,  popup.getMenu());
     popup.show();
```

But it does not show the icon.

How can I set the icon on the popup menu?

Comment: Are you showing context menu ?

Comment: i am showing menu at click on the top button

Comment: Checkout my answer which might help you.

Comment: yes i want like this and i understand about using layout xml file for menu but i dont't have any idea about showStatusPopup method because i am new in android so plz provide me a simple example

Comment: I already provided an example link in my answer check out. @user3145614

Comment: when i am using that code then application crash and getting error

Comment: Which code you are using and what error you get?

Comment: i fix error but open xml full page and i never have any idea about that code   '                 currentRowId = position;
                 currentRow = v;    
                 // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
                  location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
                 v.getLocationOnScreen(location);'

Comment: i am trying to make like this popup [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/axspH.jpg)

Comment: Try out this link https://code.google.com/p/android-icon-context-menu/

Answer (score 16):

You can create popup menu with icon using the `MenuBuilder` and `MenuPopupHelper`.

```
MenuBuilder menuBuilder =new MenuBuilder(this);
MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menuBuilder);
MenuPopupHelper optionsMenu = new MenuPopupHelper(this, menuBuilder, view);
optionsMenu.setForceShowIcon(true);

// Set Item Click Listener
menuBuilder.setCallback(new MenuBuilder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menu, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.opt1: // Handle option1 Click
                return true;
            case R.id.opt2: // Handle option2 Click
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menu) {}
});

optionsMenu.show();
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/opt1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="option 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/opt2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:title="option 2" />
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for neatest way I've seen of building an icon + text menu item. However, how have you handled the onItemClick method?

Comment: @iaindownie I have added code to handle menu clicks. I think this may help you.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! This should be the answer on all the other posts too! Far cleaner than everything else I've seen for custom/icon menus.

Comment: I have caught `MenuBuilder constructor can only be called from within the same library group`.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable icons for popup menu by using Java reflection to call a hidden method as below:

```
public static void setForceShowIcon(PopupMenu popupMenu) {
    try {
        Field[] fields = popupMenu.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popupMenu);
                Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper
                        .getClass().getName());
                Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod(
                        "setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you use the `showAsAction="never"` attribute, the default overflow does not return your icon. You could create your **own overflow** like this:

```
<item android:title=""
        android:id="@+id/overflow"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/overflow_icon">
  <menu >    
    <item android:id="@+id/back"
          android:icon="@drawable/back1"
          android:title="Back" />

    <item android:id="@+id/My_Profile"
          android:icon="@drawable/myprofile"
          android:title="My Profile" />

    <item android:id="@+id/Job_Alert"
          android:icon="@drawable/jobalert4"
          android:title="Job Alert !" />

    <item android:id="@+id/saved_job"
          android:icon="@drawable/jobapplied"
          android:title="Saved Job"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/Logout"
          android:icon="@drawable/logout"
          android:title="Logout" /> 
  </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18431605/4521603

Or if you use Xamarin / C#:

add:

```
using Java.Lang.Reflect;
```

Then use this in your code:

```
PopupMenu puMenu = new PopupMenu(Activity, v)

Field field = puMenu.Class.GetDeclaredField("mPopup");
field.Accessible = true;
Java.Lang.Object menuPopupHelper = field.Get(puMenu);
Method setForceIcons = menuPopupHelper.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", Java.Lang.Boolean.Type);
setForceIcons.Invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);

puMenu.Inflate (Resource.Menu.your_actions);
puMenu.Show ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
/**
 * Copied from android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.
 * "mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);" in the constructor does the trick :)
 * 
 * @author maikvlcek
 * @since 5:00 PM - 1/27/14
 */
public class IconizedMenu implements MenuBuilder.Callback, MenuPresenter.Callback {
        private Context mContext;
        private MenuBuilder mMenu;
        private View mAnchor;
        private MenuPopupHelper mPopup;
        private OnMenuItemClickListener mMenuItemClickListener;
        private OnDismissListener mDismissListener;

        /**
         * Callback interface used to notify the application that the menu has closed.
         */
        public interface OnDismissListener {
            /**
             * Called when the associated menu has been dismissed.
             *
             * @param menu The PopupMenu that was dismissed.
             */
            public void onDismiss(IconizedMenu menu);
        }

        /**
         * Construct a new PopupMenu.
         *
         * @param context Context for the PopupMenu.
         * @param anchor Anchor view for this popup. The popup will appear below the anchor if there
         *               is room, or above it if there is not.
         */
        public IconizedMenu(Context context, View anchor) {
            mContext = context;
            mMenu = new MenuBuilder(context);
            mMenu.setCallback(this);
            mAnchor = anchor;
            mPopup = new MenuPopupHelper(context, mMenu, anchor);
            mPopup.setCallback(this);
            mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
        }

        /**
         * @return the {@link android.view.Menu} associated with this popup. Populate the returned Menu with
         * items before calling {@link #show()}.
         *
         * @see #show()
         * @see #getMenuInflater()
         */
        public Menu getMenu() {
            return mMenu;
        }

        /**
         * @return a {@link android.view.MenuInflater} that can be used to inflate menu items from XML into the
         * menu returned by {@link #getMenu()}.
         *
         * @see #getMenu()
         */
        public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
            return new SupportMenuInflater(mContext);
        }

        /**
         * Inflate a menu resource into this PopupMenu. This is equivalent to calling
         * popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, popupMenu.getMenu()).
         * @param menuRes Menu resource to inflate
         */
        public void inflate(int menuRes) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(menuRes, mMenu);
        }

        /**
         * Show the menu popup anchored to the view specified during construction.
         * @see #dismiss()
         */
        public void show() {
            mPopup.show();
        }

        /**
         * Dismiss the menu popup.
         * @see #show()
         */
        public void dismiss() {
            mPopup.dismiss();
        }

        /**
         * Set a listener that will be notified when the user selects an item from the menu.
         *
         * @param listener Listener to notify
         */
        public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
            mMenuItemClickListener = listener;
        }

        /**
         * Set a listener that will be notified when this menu is dismissed.
         *
         * @param listener Listener to notify
         */
        public void setOnDismissListener(OnDismissListener listener) {
            mDismissListener = listener;
        }

        /**
         * @hide
         */
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menu, MenuItem item) {
            if (mMenuItemClickListener != null) {
                return mMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(item);
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * @hide
         */
        public void onCloseMenu(MenuBuilder menu, boolean allMenusAreClosing) {
            if (mDismissListener != null) {
                mDismissListener.onDismiss(this);
            }
        }

        /**
         * @hide
         */
        public boolean onOpenSubMenu(MenuBuilder subMenu) {
            if (subMenu == null) return false;

            if (!subMenu.hasVisibleItems()) {
                return true;
            }

            // Current menu will be dismissed by the normal helper, submenu will be shown in its place.
            new MenuPopupHelper(mContext, subMenu, mAnchor).show();
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * @hide
         */
        public void onCloseSubMenu(SubMenuBuilder menu) {
        }

        /**
         * @hide
         */
        public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menu) {
        }

        /**
         * Interface responsible for receiving menu item click events if the items themselves
         * do not have individual item click listeners.
         */
        public interface OnMenuItemClickListener {
            /**
             * This method will be invoked when a menu item is clicked if the item itself did
             * not already handle the event.
             *
             * @param item {@link MenuItem} that was clicked
             * @return <code>true</code> if the event was handled, <code>false</code> otherwise.
             */
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item);
        }

}
```

Source:  https://gist.github.com/mediavrog/9345938

Comment: I tried using this class and got an exception while showing popup menu.    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6

Comment: Usage of this class, as mentioned by @kevinkl3 on comment :

`public void showPopup(View v) {
        IconizedMenu popup = new IconizedMenu(this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_myactivity, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
}`

Answer (score 1):

The `setForceShowIcon` function is now public and not restricted anymore so this works!

```
private fun showPopupMenu(view: View) {
    PopupMenu(this, view).apply {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu)
        setForceShowIcon(true)
    }.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if trying this code in any activity then replace getbBaseContext() with this i.e activity context

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
```

Answer (score 0):

before  popupMenu.show(); use

```
try {
                    Field mFieldPopup=popupMenu.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                    mFieldPopup.setAccessible(true);
                    MenuPopupHelper mPopup = (MenuPopupHelper) mFieldPopup.get(popupMenu);
                    mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this By the use of Reflection if u don`t familiar with it with the help of this awesome java advanced feature u can modify the runtime behavior of applications running in the JVM you can look at the object and perform its methods on runtime and in our case we need to modify popupMenu behavior at runtime instead of extend the core class and modify it ;) hope that help Try my method working like a charm

```
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mcontext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());

    Object menuHelper;
    Class[] argTypes;
    try {
        Field fMenuHelper = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        fMenuHelper.setAccessible(true);
        menuHelper = fMenuHelper.get(popup);
        argTypes = new Class[]{boolean.class};
        menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    popup.show();




}
```