# Spinner Customize like dropbox

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I wanna create dropbox apps' spinner but I don't know how can I do. can anybody help me for this?

do you suggest tutorial and like this or GitHub links?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see some details in one over issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836385/popup-menu-with-icon-on-android).
You need to use `Popup Menu`. Or one library on [github](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)

All is explain :)