# Menu item icon now showing in sub menu

Tags: android

I'm using topup sub-menu item by group in menu item. I have created group item menu as given below menu xml code.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cycle="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<group>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/bookAppt"
            android:icon="@drawable/addsomething_gray"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:title="Book Appointment"
            cycle:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/refreshAppt"
            android:icon="@drawable/refresh_icon_dark"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:title="Refresh"
            cycle:showAsAction="never"/>

</group>
```

Every thing going perfect but submenu item icon not showing. Can anyone guide me regarding this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Pop up menus have no icons. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908985/android-options-menu-icon-wont-display . Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805756/is-it-possible-to-display-icons-in-a-popupmenu and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836385/popup-menu-with-icon-on-android for workarounds

Comment: ok, thanks to reply.

Answer (score 0):

In your code change this `cycle:showAsAction="never"` to `cycle:showAsAction="always"`.

Answer (score 0):

replace `cycle:showAsAction="never"` with  `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|always"`