# How to add images to overflow menu in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-menu, overflow-menu

I am developing the overflow menu for latest android version as i am doing this,the text items are being added to the overflow menu but item images are not adding. so please help me to know **how to add images to the overflow menu**.

I have attached screenshot and Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
    android:title="@string/new_game"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Check this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919595/popupmenu-item-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your menu xml, use the following syntax to nest menu, you will start getting the menu with icons

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/new_game"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="@string/new_game" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: They will not show up in a popup menu, only in the menu inside an actionbar

Comment: for that you have to make that custom orelse icon will not be shown there.

Comment: yup :) thats what i have suggested :)

Comment: to achive this, you need to do that in sub-menu. that icon in toolbar is by default. you can not change that.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PopupMenu does **not** support icons by default.

Alternatives include creating your own class which extends PopupMenu or more simply switching to using an ActionBar. There is a GitHub repository for an Android Compatibility popup menu with icons, which might be helpful.

Of the three options I would suggest going with the ActionBar because android seem to be heavily pushing the use of the ActionBar as best practice over the traditional header menus in their guides.

I hope this helps.

@source -> [PopupMenu Item Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919595/popupmenu-item-icons)

Comment: However if this option button is inside an Actionbar, it will be treated as a normal menu and you can check the other answer below for that case :)

Answer (score 0):

it's a common problem, Use Reflect make icon visible

```
@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  
{  

    setIconEnable(menu, true);  

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);  
}  


private void setIconEnable(Menu menu, boolean enable)  
{  
    try   
    {  
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder");  
        Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", boolean.class);  
        m.setAccessible(true);  
      m.invoke(menu, enable);  

    } catch (Exception e)   
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```