# How to show icons along with text in PopupMenu in android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-popupwindow

i have seen some tutorials but couldn't got through. I want to show icons along with item text. Here is my menu item.

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_grey600_18dp"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

Here is my java code :

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.cardMenuButton);
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.card_overflow_menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

I am developing my app in material design. But its only showing the text.

Comment: Do you want to show in actionbar or overflow menu?

Comment: I am using CardView, and i have put an action button of Overflow on right corner of that cardview. on click of that aciton button, i need to show a popup menu,

Comment: Change `app:showAsAction="always|withText"` to `app:showAsAction="never"`

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't. You can use a similar widget, [ListPopWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html), which uses an adapter to draw its content, giving you the flexibility you need.

Edit. For the width problem you have to call [setContentWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html#setContentWidth(int)). You can easily iterate on the adapter's dataset in order to calculate the max width, and use this value as parameter for `setContentWidth`

Comment: Ok, let me try that one, thnx

Comment: Thnx, precise solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can, as you can see here: [Is it possible to display icons in a PopupMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31490355/2964379)

Based on that answer, here is a custom class that shows icons:

```
public class PopupMenu extends androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu {

public PopupMenu(Context context, View anchor) {
    super(context, anchor);
    setForceShowIcon();
}

public PopupMenu(Context context, View anchor, int gravity) {
    super(context, anchor, gravity);
    setForceShowIcon();
}

public PopupMenu(Context context, View anchor, int gravity,
                 int popupStyleAttr, int popupStyleRes) {
    super(context, anchor, gravity, popupStyleAttr, popupStyleRes);
    setForceShowIcon();
}

private void setForceShowIcon() {
    try {
        Field mPopup = androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu.class
                .getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        mPopup.setAccessible(true);
        MenuPopupHelper popup = (MenuPopupHelper) mPopup.get(this);
        popup.setForceShowIcon(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```