# How to force show icons in actionBar menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

Per usual my ActionBar has a number of menu items that I set as `app:showAsAction="never"`. So when user clicks on the overflow button, these items show up but they don't have icons. How do I force the icons to show? The answer at [Is it possible to display icons in a PopupMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805756/is-it-possible-to-display-icons-in-a-popupmenu) does not answer my question as it is concerned with the popup menu. When I tried to apply it to my case it shows all items not just the ones in the overflow. Also I am anchoring it in the toolbar as I don't know how to get the overflow view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way to toggle showing an icon in the action bar overflow menu.  But I did find that someone was able to create a fully customized overflow menu:

http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html