# How to get RecyclerView position from PopupMenu onMenuItemClick

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

Using a `RecylcerView`, I'm trying to have a popup menu for each item in the list, similar to this:

[image: Popup Menu in Google Play Music playlist.]

Creating the popup menu is simple, but how do you get the position of the item clicked in `onMenuItemClicked`?

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public void showPopupMenu(View v) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_delete_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        //get position here from RecyclerView here?

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit:
            //Do position specific action
            break;
            case R.id.delete:
                //Do position specific action
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I (surprisingly) managed to answer my own question here.

In order to obtain the position from a `RecylcerView` adapter within `onMenuItemClicked` using `PopupMenu`, I created a custom implementation of `PopupMenu`.

Doing so provides much greater flexibility when using `PopupMenu`, such as [displaying icons in your menus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589919/5050806).

Look at Google's source code for `PopupMenu`, and create your own, something like `MyPopupMenu` that is exactly the same, but you can modify certain instances of what the class can do.

To complete my problem, I added an `OnClickListener` to the More button within my `RecyclerView.Adapter`. When clicked, the button calls an interface method that passes both the button view, and the adapter's current position.

In the custom implementation of `MyPopupMenu`, add the variable requirements for each constructor for an int value. Also add `int position` to the interface method `onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item, int position)` within `MyPopupMenu`.

Finally, assemble in the activity class.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.OnItemEventListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onMoreClicked(View v, int position) {
        MyPopupMenu popupMenu = new MyPopupMenu(this, v, position);
        MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_delete_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popupMenu.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item, int position) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit:
                //Do position specific action with int position
                break;
            case R.id.delete:
                //Do position specific action with int position
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final OnItemEventListener onItemEventListener;

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageButton more;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            more = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_more_button);
        }
    }

    public NewGameAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        viewHolder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onItemEventListener.onMoreClicked(viewHolder.more, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

        return viewHolder;
    }

    interface OnItemEventListener {
        void onMoreClicked(View v, int position);
    }
}
```

Let me know what you guys think!

Comment: Seriously, thank you so much for this. I have been searching all day for an easy way to implement this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hello dear you need to use this way in adapter

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecentPlayedAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.menudotes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(context, holder.menudotes, Gravity.START);
                    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popupmenu1,popupMenu.getMenu());
                    popupMenu.show();
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.download:
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    //Do position specific action with int position
                                    break;
                                case R.id.playlist:
                                    //Do position specific action with int position
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Playlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    break;
                                case R.id.share:
                                    //Do position specific action with int position
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                    break;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
    }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in the code snippet you've shown, it doesn't correlate with the available image.

Please provide your onBindViewHolder code. That is where the menu item's on click listener should be set.